# Does the mlocate.db generated by my updatedb cron job also applies to 'find'?

Tags: find, locate

Reviewing the find man pages for Linux and for Unix, I came across the fact that the mlocate.db seems to apply to 'find' based searches as well as to 'locate' executions in certain flavors of Ux. So an 'updatedb' cron job would benefit both command searches in terms of speed.
I could not corroborate that for the Linux Bash environment.

How is it in either a POSIX compliant or a non POSIX compliant Bash environment for Linux-Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, they're both different commands (locate & find) and work separately from each other.
locate will check the mlocate.db database to see if a file is registered. If you have new files and updatedb hasn't run, your locate will not show any of the new files you're looking for.
find on the other hand, will recursively go through the given path to check which files are currently there. Whenever a new file is placed in the path, find will return it. This proves that find does not rely on the mlocate.db file.

Comment: Jakke,I understand quite well what you write, but it is not conclusive. If 'locate' does not work without an mlocate.db, it means that 'locate' requires mlocate.db. However if 'find' works with no mlocate.db file, it does not imply that it may not make use of it when the file exists.

Comment: If you issue the command `touch test.file;find . |grep test.file`, find will respond immediately with a result, that test.file has been found. Even though it's virtually impossible that `updatedb` has updated mlocate.db between the `touch` and `find` command. IF `find` would make use of mlocate.db, it would only be a decrease in performance because it would first check mlocate.db and then still have to browse through the given path. It really doesn't make much sense that `find` would be using mlocate.db, that's all I'm saying, and that makes sense (to me anyways).

Comment: The kernel will make use of caching in RAM though. You will find that subsequent issues of the find command will run much faster than the initial command. This has nothing to do with mlocate.db however, just with kernel caching to improve performance. You can read more about it here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1806925

Comment: Ok, Jakke. I'll take that as a point. Thanks for your insight.